# Moving one file at a time as part of a Win7 command-line batch file

Tags: windows, file, command-line, batch-file, move

I need to move files from one folder to another--but one at a time, not all at once--so that each file can be processed separately with a command-line tool before proceeding with the next file. And I need the files moved in sequential order by name.

I've already got the rest of the batch file (the part that processes each file) figured out, but it would be nice if I didn't have to move each file myself, and could just automate the entire process.

Comment: How would you know when the other process is done with the file it currently has?  Also, I would absolutely not set things up like this.  The process handling files that appear in the new folder should be able to deal with files showing up at any time, else you have a very strong dependency that WILL break on you at some point.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
move \from\*.* \to
```

read `HELP FOR` and try this bat file

```
@echo off
for %%a in (d:\from\*.*) do (
  echo move %%a d:\to
  echo command-line-tool d:\to\%%~xna
)
```

try it from different locations and some extreme cases, `from` and `to` non existent, `from` empry, `to` non empty, etc)  and when absolutely satisfied remove the `echo` command.